# How to install a golang package without having git installed in the system?

Tags: git, go

I'm trying to install a go package by using the command `go get -u github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline` in my project but it won't install. This is the error that I'm getting.

`go: missing Git command. See https://golang.org/s/gogetcmd
 package github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline: exec: "git": executable file not found in %PATH%`

I looked for the `go get` command in the documentation and it says

> The go get fetching of source code is done by using one of the following tools expected to be found on your system:
>
> svn - Subversion, download at: http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html
>
> hg - Mercurial, download at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/downloads
>
> git - Git, download at http://git-scm.com/downloads
>
> bzr - Bazaar, download at http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/Download

I understand the error occurs because I don't have any of the tools mentioned installed in my system but it's something I can't help myself with because of a few restrictions. Please tell me if there's any workaround available.

Comment: You need to have the source code. One workaround is to retype the whole source code into your local editor. No serious. Install git or download the dependencies with go get on a machine (or a container) with git installed. Anything else is doomed to fail.

Comment: If the machine does not (cannot) have the needed dev tools installed then do you dev work elsewhere then scp your compiled binaries over to that box for execution ... personally I use a VPS on a remote location for all my dev work because no local laptop/desktop can compete with a VPS on bandwidth/ram etc... for the price of two beers a month you get yourself a decent VPS at https://www.hetzner.com/cloud ... if you wish to use a local editor then install sshfs and locally mount remote dir to make local file edits

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the package from github, If that package depends on any-other package which is not from stdlib(standard library), you need to do the same for all and then `cd` to the directory where your project exists and then do:

```
go build
```

Don't forget to maintain the directory structure in your `GOPATH`, like `github.com/xxx/xxx` or `golang.org/x/tools/xxx`